# Prevent page reload on html anchor tag

Tags: javascript

How do i prevent the anchor tag from reloading my page when i click it using js

```
<a href='?code=$user_code' class=''>view user</a>
```

Comment: How is it supposed to send the `code=$user_code` parameter and show the result without reloading the page?

Comment: What should it do instead of reloading the page? You can add an event listener that calls `event.preventDefault()` to prevent following the link. It can use AJAX to call the server, but then what is it supposed to do?

Comment: i have fetch data from the database add i what to display the data on the some page and if the page reload the data is not displayed

Comment: There are a couple of ways you might do this, but there's not enough information to suggest an appropriate solution.

Comment: As I said above. Use `preventDefault()` to prevent reloading the page, and use AJAX to fetch the data you want to display.

Answer (score 2):

Like [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) suggested in the comments, you can add an event listener to the anchor element that calls `event.preventDefault()` to prevent page reload. Inside the event listener you can fetch the data from database.

```html
<a id="my-anchor" href='?code=$user_code'>view user</a>
```

```js
var myAnchor = document.getElementById('my-anchor');

myAnchor.onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var href = myAnchor.getAttribute('href');

  // fetch data from database
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tojx5ske/

Another option is to create an anchor with `href="#"` and pass the real href to the event listener using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes):

```html
<a id="my-anchor" href="#" data-href='?code=$user_code'>view user</a>
```

```js
var myAnchor = document.getElementById('my-anchor');

myAnchor.onclick = function(e) {
  var href = myAnchor.dataset.href;

  // fetch data from database
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tojx5ske/1/